# Order by created time + timeout, MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, "Questions": A list of questions, "QResults" The users results to these questions. The questions have a timeout in hrs before they are asked again.

```
Table: Questions
   ID
   Timeout - The amount of time before asking the question again 

Table: Results
   ID 
   Created (timestamp) - When this record was added. 
   Questions_ID - A FK to the Question table
```

Example data

```
Table: Questions
 ID | Timeout (hrs) 
--------------
  1 | 1    
  8 | 6 
 15 | 1 
 55 | 1

Table: QResults
ID | Created            | Q_ID 
-------------------------------
 1 | Jan 24, 2012 00:00 |    1 
 2 | Jan 24, 2012 06:05 |   15 
 3 | Jan 24, 2012 02:00 |    8 
 4 | Jan 24, 2012 01:00 |    1 
 5 | Jan 24, 2012 02:00 |    1
```

What I am looking for is a query that will sort the questions based on the last time the question was answered + the timeout. If the question has never been answered then it should be pushed to the top of the list.

For example if the query was run on the above data it would produce the following data set.

```
The result of the query I am looking for. 
ID | timeout + created aka eligible
-------------------------------
55 | Jan 01, 1970 01:00 *(1) See note below*
 1 | Jan 24, 2012 03:00 *(2) See note below* 
 8 | Jan 24, 2012 07:05
15 | Jan 24, 2012 08:00
```

*Note: (1) It does not matter what the date is for id=55, as long as it showes up first. because currently there is not an QResults for it. (2) This has a value of 3hr as it use the newest answer creation time + timeout.

Let me put this another way. I am looking for a question that has the lowest value for (last asked + timeout). If the question has been answered 3 times it should use the newest question answered time + timeout for the eligible value. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't check the syntax right now but I'd do something like this.

- get a lowest record for each ID in your questions table
- append to those records all of the records in your results table plus the timeout from your question table
- get the max for the result by ID

Syntax would be something like...

**Updated syntax**

```
select ID, MAX(Timeout) as Timeout
from
(
  (
  select ID, cast('1970-01-01 01:00' as DATETIME) as Timeout
  from Questions
  ) 
union all
  (
  select q.ID, r.created + INTERVAL q.Timeout hour as Timeout
  from QResults as r, Questions as q
  where r.q_ID=q.ID
  ) 
) c
group by ID
order by MAX(Timeout) asc
```

This gives me the following results. (Note the ordering difference from yours. I think this is what you meant.)

```
ID  Timeout
55  1970-01-01 01:00:00
1   2012-01-24 03:00:00
15  2012-01-24 07:05:00
8   2012-01-24 08:00:00
```

If this runs slowly, you may want to get the max date by id on your Qresults table before you do the join to the questions table to add the timeout. I wouldn't bother doing this though unless you need to as it will complicate the query and the mysql optimizer may be smart enough to figure that out on its own.

Comment: I get the following error. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'b ) c group by ID order by MAX(timeout) desc' at line 13

Comment: ok. Fixed syntax. If it still isn't working, double check that the letters and case of table names and column names in the query are exactly what you have in your DB.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, but I'll leave it to you to optimize:

```
(select q.id as id, date_add(r.created, interval q.timeout hour) as eligible
from questions q, qresults r
where q.id = r.id)
union (
select q.id as id, '1970-01-01 00:00:00' as eligible
from questions q
where q.id not in
    (select id from qresults r)
)
order by 2 asc
```

Comment: I get this following error 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'union ( select q.id as id, timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' as eligible from qu' at line 4

Comment: Sorry, I did not check the syntax.  Fixed.  (Or should I say, the _syntax_ is fixed...)

Comment: Thank you, the syntax has been fixed and the query works. (Woot!) The next problem is because there are multiple QResults for each question  the query returns a table with duplicate values for each questions.id. I have updated the question and added another example.